# What do I call a non-MVC pattern?

Tags: architecture, mvc

I am finishing my project and in my thesis I am explaining why I used an **MVC** pattern to build my website, and have stated the advantages of designing it this way.

However, if I had **not** used MVC and had built my website from scratch with all the functions for data, processing, and display into each page, what would that have been called in terms of architecture?

For example, I would have had one PHP file that has all of the code and functions that it needs. Would it have been called "a standard website architecture"?

Comment: An inferior design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think "monolithic" would be the term here. To my mind this implies no separation of concerns or layering, which is what you are describing.

Comment: This works, so long as he goes out of his way to define the term before using it in his paper.

Answer (score 8):

The architecture that you are describing can be referred to as [Model 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1)

> In Model 1, a request is made to a JSP or servlet and then that JSP or servlet handles all responsibilities for the request, including processing the request, validating data, handling the business logic, and generating a response. The Model 1 architecture is commonly used in smaller, simple task applications due to its ease of development.
>
> Although conceptually simple, this architecture is not conducive to large-scale application development because, inevitably, a great deal of functionality is duplicated in each JSP. Also, the Model 1 architecture unnecessarily ties together the business logic and presentation logic of the application. Combining business logic with presentation logic makes it hard to introduce a new 'view' or access point in an application...
>
> [image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Model_1.png/390px-Model_1.png]

Comment: Isn't "Model 1" specific to J2EE architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Would it be 1 php file?

Wouldn't it be more likely to be many php files, each file containing the html content and php code?

If so then the architecture would be called 'Page Controller' as apposed to the 'Front Controller' typically found in mvc.